# Pandas Dataframe: Dropping Selected rows with 0.0 float type values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, subset, delete-row

Please I have a dataset that contains amount as float type. Some of the rows contain values of 0.00 and because they skew the dataset, I need to drop them. I have temporarily set the "Amount" to index and sorted the value as well.
Afterwards, I attempted to drop the rows after subsetting with **iloc** but eep getting error message in the form **ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 3)**

'''mortgage = mortgage.set_index('Gross Loan Amount').sort_values('Gross Loan Amount')
mortgage.drop([mortgage.loc[0.0]])'''

I equally tried this:
'''mortgage.drop(mortgage.loc[0.0])'''
it flagged the error of the form **KeyError: "[Column_names] not found in axis"**

Please how else can I accomplish the task?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a boolean frame and then use any

```
df = df[~(df == 0).any(axis=1)]
```

in this code, all rows that have at least one zero in their data has been removed. It's a simple way for your challenge.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
Please I have 69764 rows of data, I intend to drop just 39 rows with amount as 0.0(float type). The solution you suggested left me with 570 rows.

Comment: the reason for this result can be various things, maybe your data didn't clean very well and it needs to remove some data like null or Nan. if you run this solution for another plain example, you will get an expected result

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I get your problem. I created this sample dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': [200.04,100.00,0.00,150.15,69.98,0.10,2.90,34.6,12.6,0.00,0.00]})
df
    Values
0   200.04
1   100.00
2     0.00
3   150.15
4    69.98
5     0.10
6     2.90
7    34.60
8    12.60
9     0.00
10    0.00
```

Now, in order to get rid of the 0.00 values, you just have to do this:

```
df = df[df['Values'] != 0.00]
```

Output:

```
df
    Values
0   200.04
1   100.00
3   150.15
4    69.98
5     0.10
6     2.90
7    34.60
8    12.60
```